# resize drawables and layouts for given display

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android application that needs to run on one specific device. Its display:
 - is considered as **ldpi** (according to my calculations and getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi)
 - has width of 1440px, from which Android should see only **940px**.
When I call getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels it is really **940**, but actually **layout-w1140dp** gets loaded, and not **layout-w940dp** (I have created several layout folders just to see what will be loaded).

The main issue I have is that even though I have set the width of my activity's main layout to be **940dp**, what I observe is that it is actually filling like 3/4 of the screen width. It seems like Android resizes the drawables from the **drawable-ldpi** folder when displaying on a display with 940px width.
Am I getting it wrong to think that if you have the drawables and layout files for the specific display in the correct folders and in a layout you set 940dp, it should really be 940px on that display?

---

So I replaced every **dp** with **px** in my layout file and now it seems fine.
Obviously I need to re-read more carefully Android's documentation, because I had wrong understanding of dp. I have some new questions, but I guess it will be better to ask in a separate questions.

Comment: `is considered as ldpi` ... **really**? how many dpi does it report? `So I replaced every dp with px` this is only valid for **mdpi**, not ldpi. You should **always** use `dp` for views and `sp` for text sizes.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein It reports 125dpi. And why I should **always** use dp for views?

Comment: 125 dpi is **ldpi**, without any doubt. Because dp are **scalable**. px aren't. If you are to support **one device only**, then just don't care. But this shouldn't be your aim.

Comment: Actually it is exactly what I aim for (I have written in the first sentence of the question, maybe it was not that clear). This application needs to run on only one specific device. And using **dp** didn't work for me, but **px** seemed to work (at least on emulator, I will try tomorrow on the real device).

Answer (score 0):

DP and px are very different things. DP are density independent pixels, see [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) for some more information on the difference.